# How to configure react typescript project having folder paths accessible like '@components/'

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-typescript

I want to change the relative url imports for react-typescript project. Basically from this crap `../../../contexts/AuthContext` to just clean `@contexts/AuthContexts`.

I have tried the following with **tsconfig.json** :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
        "@contexts/*": ["src/contexts/*"]
    }
}
```

But I am still getting error like `@contexts/AuthContexts` not found. And yes I can confirm that there is a file called AuthContext in that location with exports as `AuthProvider`.

I have created this app with `npm create vite@latest` using typescript as a template.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `resolve.alias` in vite.config.ts file

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
    },
  },
});
```